# Modifying Graph Hopper with traffic_signal tags

Tags: graphhopper

We want to use graph hopper to route by avoiding all traffic_signals.

**These are the steps we have done so far:**

1. Download the graphhopper-master branch (https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/)
2. Ran the shell script (`$ ./graphhopper.sh web europe_andorra.osm`)

   2a. That worked.
3. Tried to edit the `config.properties` file by changing this : (`osmreader.acceptWay=CAR,FOOT`)

   3a. We get several errors in the console :

   `java.lang.IllegalStateException: multiple encoders are active. cannot return one:car,foot`
   is the main one
4. Tried to edit the source code, without changing the config file, for example we modified this code in the class:

   `AbstractFlagEncoder()`

   in the function:

   `public long analyzeNodeTags( OSMNode node )`

   We added this section:

   `if ((node.hasTag("highway", "traffic_signals") || node.hasTag("traffic_signals")))

           return directionBitMask;`
5. No changes to the code is visible.

We are blindly changing and editing the code, could you give us a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: We have found that the shell file uses the .jars in the target folder to run. We are using deleting this folder, editing, running. To make changes to the code. But the error when changing the properties file still happens.

Comment: 'We are blindly changing' -> why not set up a unit test where you see that it works?

Comment: 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: multiple encoders are active. cannot return one:car,foot' -> either use one vehicle or disable CH